# Saving a tweaked form request data in Django

Tags: python, django

My form accepts URL as input and before the URL can work it should have `'http'` or `'https'`, example: `http://apexrice.com`. So my issue is that some times users enter the `url` without `https`.

so am trying to tweak the data and add `http` or `https`

here's a sample code:

```
def get_link(request):

form = shortenerModelForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    check_http = form.cleaned_data['link']
    print(check_http)
    if request.is_secure() and not check_http.startswith('https'):
        link = f'https://{check_http}'
        u = form.save(link)
    elif not request.is_secure() and not check_http.startswith('http'):
        link = f'http://{check_http}'
        u = form.save(link)
    else:
        u = form.save()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'users': users})


return render(request, 'index.html', {
    'form': form,
})
```

So doing `form.save()` does not save the changes to databese, but it saves the original data. Please how do I save the changes to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just figured out what I was missing. I got the answer from [saving-changes-to-objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects)

So I first saved the instance to database, then I updated the value in the database before I return the final output. Thanks